# Do I have to add await when I call async function?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I have this async funtion to get call :

```
reviewSchema.statics.calcAverageRatings = async function(tourId) {
  const stats = await this.aggregate([
    {
      $match: { tour: tourId }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '$tour',
        nRating: { $sum: 1 },
        avgRating: { $avg: '$rating' }
      }
    }
  ]);

  console.log(stats);

  await Tour.findByIdAndUpdate(tourId, {
    ratingsAverage: stats[0].avgRating,
    ratingsQuantity: stats[0].nRating
  });
};
```

And ı have that function too that calling this function :

```
reviewSchema.post(/^findOneAnd/, async function() {
  await this.document.constructor.calcAverageRatings(this.document.tour);
});
```

So, me and my friend get confused about that: 
this function also working correct without async/await like this way:

```
reviewSchema.post(/^findOneAnd/, function() {
  this.document.constructor.calcAverageRatings(this.document.tour);
});
```

What is the different between them. Is it wrong to call function without await, or is it wrong to call it with await !

Comment: Short answer: NO.
you dont need, and nothing actually will happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, an `async` function always returns a promise.  So, when you call an `async` function what you get back is a promise.  Usually, you want to know either when the asynchronous operation was done or you want to get the result or error from the asynchronous operation.

To do either one of those (get resolved value or know when they are done), you need either `await` or `.then()` and `.catch()`.

So, there are very occasionally operations that can be "fire and forget" and can never reject, but that is rare (remember, you HAVE to catch all rejections somewhere).  So, when a promise is being returned, you are usually using either `await` or `.then()` and `.catch()`.

To repeat, the only time you don't use one of those options with the promise returned from an `async` operation is:

1. The promise is just getting returned back to a higher level (where it will be handled there appropriately).
2. The operation is a "fire and forget" type operation that none of your code cares when it will be done, doesn't care what its resolved value is AND it can never reject.

In this specific example:

```
reviewSchema.post(/^findOneAnd/, async function() {
  await this.document.constructor.calcAverageRatings(this.document.tour);
});
```

You would have to apply the above tests to it.  I don't know the overall context of what `reviewSchema.post()` is supposed to do.  When we look at `calcAverageERatings()`, we see database operations that CAN fail so the promise it returns can reject so immediately, it fails one of the tests.  It can reject so someone needs to handle the rejected promise and do something appropriate.

If this is an Express request handler, then you also need so send a response to the POST request when you're done processing it and probably send a different response if successful vs. error.